# Map initialized fine, but rotation not working

Tags: api, rotation, maps

I have site (index.html) on https://podaci.com/rutizam.
One of the maps (have few, not shown in the same time) should be rotated.

I used sample at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/webgl/webgl-tilt-rotation#setting_tilt_and_heading
and it works fine as separate test file.

On the site, map to rotate is declared, regarding the sample, as

```
    mapaTRACK = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById( "mapaTRACK" ), {
        zoom              : zoomStartValue,
        scaleControl      : true,
        mapTypeId         : google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP,
        center            : {lat: 44.300, lng: 20.644},
        draggableCursor   : 'crosshair',
        heading           : 90, 
        mapId             : "90f87356969d889c",
        tilt              : 45,  
      }
    );
```

I included reference from sample

'script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"'

in my source.

The problem: as application starts, mapaTRACK.getHeading() becomes 0, mapaTRACK.heading is 0, and mapaTRACK.setHeading( value ) gives no result.

Checked: during whole initMap (at google callback) and initPage (onload procedure), step by step, both mapaTRACK.getHeading() and mapaTRACK.setHeading( value ) worked fine. But, as the page becomes active, first check shows mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. For a while the instruction "src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?..." wasn't at the bottom of the body section, which I didn't notice, because everything (except rotation) worked properly on all maps.
I'm sorry I wasted some of your time.